# CSS Selector Bootstrap navbar menu links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap newb here. Having trouble finding the right selector to color the links in the menu. I've tried .nav a:link, a:hover but the hyperlink and hover color stays on the default blue/grey.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    <div class="containerNav">
        <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Test</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social media <b class = "caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Google+</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end container -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end nav bar -->
```

Using bootstrap 3.2. http://jsfiddle.net/nwjob2e0/ . (In JS fiddle my icon-bar is hidden under where it says 'result' so if youpress that the list should expand and you can see what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/nwjob2e0/#&togetherjs=ioVBLnT3mA - collab

Comment: Simply override the color by `a { color: gold; }`. For navbar try `.navbar a { color: gold; }` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/nwjob2e0/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #999;
}
```

And for Active, Hover, Focus:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

**Update:**

To modify dropdowns (like social media menu in your example):

```
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwjob2e0/6/)**

**Update2:**

Also you can use **[This Online Tool](http://bootstrap3-menu.codedorigin.com/#sthash.4Nx3qVms.dpbs)** to generate a Bootstrap NavBar easily.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Which one of those rules make the background turn grey when the user hovers? http://jsfiddle.net/5q72yhof/1/#&togetherjs=1QJ35iA4Mq

Comment: Set the background-color in second part of answer, check the updated answer.

Comment: Does that also include when the user selects Social Media from the drop down? On my browser (Chrome) the background for Social Media when selected is still the default bootstrap grey. For all others it's fine (turns black) I think i'm not selecting it properly.

Comment: I think its the navHeaderCollapse hmm

Comment: Yes my question has extended from the original. Sorry I wasn't clear. When the Social media dropdown list is activated by the user but then hovers on another link outside that list for e.g. About, the original Social media link is coloured grey and I have no idea where it coming from. It could be from the dropdown class?

Comment: Great stuff. it works. Thanks for that. Btw how did you generate those selectors so quickly?